# Restore PostgreSQL Data from root folder

Tags: postgresql

Recently I have done a mistake. I have migrated my server. During migration, I have dumped all databases except one. Now I need that database. Fortunately or unfortunately I have taken a backup of the PostgreSQL root folder as zip fie. Can I restore the data from that root folder?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that you are talking about the data directory when you say “root folder”.

If the server was stopped while you copied the data directory, you are good. Just restore the files and start PostgreSQL.

If the server was running while you copied the files, you can also restore it and start the server, but your database will probably be corrupted. With some luck you will be able to run a `pg_dump` and salvage your data that way. If that fails, or the dump does not restore cleanly, you'll need to call in somebody who is skilled with PostgreSQL database corruption.

Comment: Unfortunately, database was running but there was no operation in DB running as all the APIs were closed at that time. Is there any luck?

Comment: Try and see. Keep your fingers crossed. There are no guarantees, there might be data missing or too much, could be anything.